# Material-UI TreeView height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, treeview

Does anyone know how to set material-ui TreeView fixed height or height fitted to display?
[image]

I want scrollbar to be shown when TreeView content height become 100 for example or 100% of display height. Now when I expand my tree all content that didn't fit, goes away of the display bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify the `root` style of `TreeView` component. Add your desirable height to the `height` attribute and then assing `overflow` to auto to make the whole `TreeView` component scrollable. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xzkwk)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: "50px",
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400,
    overflow: "auto"
  }
});
<TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
    >
```